# Why irrelevant network activity improves slow loopback performance?

Tags: java, windows, networking, loopback

I have a java application (based on [dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io)) that accepts HTTP requests, performs some in memory computations and returns HTTP responses.

I have another java application ([jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)) which load tests the first one by sending requests with random parameters.

When I run the test (both the test and applications on the same laptop) I get bad performance: throughput is low (25 requests per second (rps)), latency is high (150ms). What interesting is that CPU usage of the application is low too (10%). It seems that the application spends much time waiting for network calls.

But when some other network activity (not all, playing YouTube video doesn't help) is going on, for instance when I do a Skype call or open local auto-refreshing [grafana](https://grafana.com/) dashboard the situation changes. CPU usage by the application increases to 50%, throughput increases to 70-90 rps, latency decreases to 50ms.

It seems that irrelevant network activity somehow speed-ups network calls between the application and test. Can anybody explain that behavior?

Win 10, Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a computer with power saving settings? (Such as a laptop on battery power?)

Try to turn off all kinds of power saving, on CPU as well as other devices.